# d3.timeDay function starts in year 2023 and runs backwards to infinity

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my d3.js chart, I have data from 2002 to 2023.

I verified this using `x.domain()`, which returns:

```
0: Wed Jul 31 2002 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
1: Mon Jul 31 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
```

Then I try to create x-axis ticks:

```
let x = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([0, 600]);
let fiscal_year_ends_month = 10;
d3.axisBottom(x)
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%y")).ticks(data.length < 60 ? d3.timeMonth : d3.timeYear)
.ticks(d3.timeDay.filter(function(d) {
    return d.getMonth() === fiscal_year_ends_month;
}))
```

This is supposed to iterate through all the dates in the range, find the ones that meet the condition that the month is what I input, and create the ticks.

However, it runs for infinity.

Specifically, if I do this:

```
.ticks(d3.timeDay.filter(function(d) {
    console.log(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
    return d.getMonth() === fiscal_year_ends_month;
}))
```

It appears to start at the end of my `x.domain` (2023) and run backwards to infinity. I let it run for a while now and the last output of `console.log` was June 10, 322 B.C.:

```
-322 5 10
```

Needless to say, my chart of stock market data should not start in the 4th century B.C.

Why isn't the process running only through the dates in my `x.domain()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue can be re-created like this:

```
.ticks(d3.timeDay.filter(function(d) {
  console.log(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
  return false; // <--- generates infinite loop backward in time !!
}))
```

This suggests an issue in your input data with regards to the month index you are trying to filter on. It also suggests there's a bug in the library that let's this happen...

With `fiscal_year_ends_month = 10` I assume you are looking to only have November ticks for each year of data ? There is a [`d3.timeMonth`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/main/README.md#timeMonth) interval that you can use for this purpose e.g.:

```
.ticks(d3.timeMonth.filter(function(d) {
  return d.getMonth() === fiscal_year_ends_month;
}));
```

Working example:

```js
// your constant
const fiscal_year_ends_month = 10;

// sample data
let data = [];
for (let i= 0; i<2370; i++) {
  let d = new Date()
  data.push({
    dt: d.setDate(d.getDate() + i),
    val: i
  });
}

// time scale
let x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.dt))
  .range([0, 540]);
  
// render
let svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(30,30)");
  
let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%y"))
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth.filter(function(d) {
    return d.getMonth() === fiscal_year_ends_month;
  }));
  
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,90)")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried `timeMonth` now but the same issue remains - it's still an infinite loop into the past, the difference is that now it iterates every month instead of every day. I'm confused how this can happen with `x.domain()` being correct - I would assume the library would use the domain for the `timeMonth`/`timeDay` limits.

Comment: And yes, in this example I just want ticks in November, hence `d.getMonth() === fiscal_year_ends_month` is correct, but the infinite loop is still there.

Comment: Can you check your data and ensure that there is at least one date value that will create a `true` in the filter ? It feels like there's no matches in there and even though your `domain` is good you're running into this weird and buggy behaviour.

Comment: You're right, the condition was never true (because of an unrelated problem with the data). Still weird buggy behavior as you say.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I reported this to D3 and they just told me that an infinite loop is not a bug (?!). [see issue here](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/3543)